# My query returns null in wordpress and I don't know why

Tags: php, wordpress

What's wrong with this query? It always returns NULL.

```php
$recipes = $wpdb->get_results(
       "SELECT ID FROM ".$wpdb->posts." WHERE post_author = %d AND post_status IN ('draft','publish') AND post_type = 'recipes' ", $current_user->ID
        );
```

Comment: Have you checked your actual database and have you checked the variables you're plugging in to make sure the values of them are accurate?

Comment: yes and yes. I did all of those.

Comment: Use `WP_Query` or `get_posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_results takes output type as second parameter.  You're missing prepare method if you want to do it like this. It should be something like

```
 $recipes = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare ("SELECT ID FROM ".$wpdb->posts." 
 WHERE post_author = %d 
 AND post_status IN ('draft','publish') 
 AND post_type = 'recipes' ", $current_user->ID));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
global $post;
global $wpdb;

$sel_query = "SELECT id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE post_author = ".$current_user->ID." AND post_status IN ('draft','publish') AND post_type = 'recipes' ";
$totaldata = $wpdb->get_results($sel_query);

return $totaldata;
```